# AngularJS - Service return value

Tags: angularjs, wordpress, cookies

I've an app using JSON user API wordpress plugin.
I've this service to validate user cookie. First i call an API for cookie name then i try to validate cookie.

```
angular.module('app').service('AuthService', AuthService);

AuthService.$inject = ['$http'];
function AuthService($http) {
return {
    isAuthenticated: isAuthenticated
};
function isAuthenticated(){
    return $http.get('http://somesite/pCookie.php')
      .then(function (response) {
        var authCookieName = response.data.response;
        var authCookie = getCookie(authCookieName);
        var validity;            
        $http.get('http://somesite/api/user/validate_auth_cookie/?cookie='+authCookie)
            .then(function (response) {
                validity = response.data; 

            });

        return validity;
    });
}
}
```

The problems are:
is there any other method that provide LOGGED_IN_COOKIE cookie name?
validity is undefined because of nested functions. How can i resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the first `$http.get` within `isAuthenticated` returns a promise, you should do this instead:

```
function isAuthenticated() {
  return $http.get('http://somesite/pCookie.php')
    .then(function (response) {
      var authCookieName = response.data.response;
      var authCookie = getCookie(authCookieName);
      return authCookie;
    })
    .then(function (authCookie) {
      return $http.get('http://somesite/api/user/validate_auth_cookie/?cookie='+authCookie);
    })
    .then(function (response) {
      return response.data;
    });
}
```